# Ajax call not executing as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax call that is not executing how I would expect. I am receiving an error from the browser of "jquery-1.10.2.js:8157 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FileGuid' of undefined". I have break points in my CS file at the start of both the GetExportData and Download functions but neither one of them are ever hit.

```
function generateExportFile() {
        var datefrom = $('#tab_MHSubpay_datefrom').ejDatePicker("getValue");
        var dateto = $('#tab_MHSubpay_dateto').ejDatePicker("getValue");
        var show = $('#tab_MHSubpay_show').ejDropDownList("getSelectedValue");
        var service = $('#tab_MHSubpay_serviceType').ejDropDownList("getSelectedValue");
        var phase = $('#tab_MHSubpay_phaseCode').ejDropDownList("getSelectedValue");


        $('#accwpopup').ejWaitingPopup({
            showOnInit: true,
            text: "Generating file...",
            target: "#tbldata"
        });

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetExportData", "MHSubpay")',
            data: {
                datefrom: datefrom,
                dateto: dateto,
                show: show,
                service: service,
                phase: phase
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#accwpopup').ejWaitingPopup('destroy');
                window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "MHSubpay")?fileGuid=' + data.Data.FileGuid + '&filename=' + data.Data.FileName;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#accwpopup').ejWaitingPopup('destroy');
                showMessage("An error ocurred trying to generate the file", false);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The affected line is this, because this is the only line where you try to access the `FileGuid` property:

```js
window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "MHSubpay")?fileGuid=' + data.Data.FileGuid + '&filename=' + data.Data.FileName;
```

More specifically this part of the line:

```js
data.Data.FileGuid
```

Based on that the Ajax request executes successfully, but the response doesn't have a `Data` propery.

What I'd do is I'd put a `console.log(data)` at the first line of the success method to see what's in the response body.

Sidenote: this is JavaScript code which runs in the browser, so it doesn't make much sense to put breakpoints in this CS file which runs on the server side.

Comment: The break points were just to see if the GetExportData function was even being hit on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a really dumb mistake that I just kept glossing over. I never updated the server side code, which I recycled from another controller, to be an HttpGet function rather than an HttpPost. Once I switched that the call went through properly.